# Complete recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

There are many questions about $k$-order recurrence relations and answers on how to solve them at the forum. But is there a thing as a "complete" or "full" recurrence relation (I don't know their name)? I mean a recurrence relation where the $n$-th term depends on all that came before, like
$$
y_{n+1} = a_n y_n + \cdots + a_0y_0.
$$
How could such recurrence be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ is a given sequence, and assuming it is the *same* sequence at each step: $y_{n+1}=a_n y_n+(a_{n-1}y_{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0y_0)=a_ny_n + y_n = (a_n+1)y_n\,$. Then, by telescoping, $y_n = y_0 \cdot \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (a_k+1)\,$.

Comment: Nice. But what if it is not the same sequecence at every iteration? Maybe making the notation better:

Comment: Nice. But what if it is not the same sequence at every iteration? Maybe making the notation clearer: $y_{n+1}=a_{n,n+1}y_n+a_{n-1,n+1}y_{n-1}+⋯+a_{0,n+1}y_0$.

Comment: @user308522 You'll have to decide on what the question is which you mean to ask. In the most general form, a "*complete*" recurrence relation would be something like $y_{n+1}=f_n(y_n,y_{n-1},\cdots,y_0)$ but it's doubtful you'll find many useful properties without *some* additional assumptions on $f_n$.